# how do I uninstall gfortran10

Tags: python, anaconda, homebrew

I downloaded it from Homebrew, so the typical uninstall code is not working for me.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/gfortran /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Comment: Have you tried `brew uninstall gfortran`?

Comment: that has not worked, so I uninstalled homebrew entirely

Comment: that has not worked, so I uninstalled homebrew entirely

Comment: Did it out any error messages when running the uninstall command?

Comment: no, but the program was still there when i used brew list

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out where gfortran points to first -- `ls -l /usr/local/bin/gfortran` -- on my system, this yields `../Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/bin/gfortran`, which tells me that it is from the gcc formula.
2. Having found this, `brew uninstall gcc` will remove it.

Comment: for some reason, this didn't work, so I uninstalled Homebrew entirely

Comment: So after running `brew uninstall gcc`, `gcc` is still in `brew list` after the command is run? have you tried reinstalling Homebrew? Does it work now?